# Is an observable just a partially applied function?

Tags: javascript, observable

For clarity, this question applies to the observable pattern implemented in javascript (the code I'll write here is all ES6).

Recently I've been trying to figure out how observables actually work. I found a couple articles/posts that describe them within the context of creating a class that takes a function as its constructor argument. This function just waits around for an observer, and the method `.subscribe(observer)` finally triggers this function with the observer as argument.

Here is my attempt at creating an observable with class syntax that implements an interval with a limit on the number of interval ticks (so that there is something to complete with):

```
class Observable {
  constructor(pushFn) {
    this.pushFn = pushFn; // waits for observer as argument
  }
  static interval(milliSecs, tickLimit) {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      if (milliSecs <= 0) {
        observer.error("Invalid interval. Interval value must be larger than 0.")
      } else {
        let tick = 0;
        const inter = setInterval(() => {
          observer.next(tick += 1);
          if (tick === tickLimit) {
            clearInterval(inter);
            observer.complete(tickLimit);
          }
        }, milliSecs);
      }
    });
  }
  subscribe(observer) {
    return this.pushFn(observer);
  }
}
```

What I find kind of surprising (given that I always thought of observables as some sort mysterious super complex thing) is that this functionality can be replicated with the following function:

```
const observableIntervalOf = (milliSecs, tickLimit) => observer => {
  if (milliSecs <= 0) {
    observer.error("Invalid interval. Interval value must be larger than 0.")
  } else {
    let tick = 0;
    const inter = setInterval(() => {
      observer.next(tick += 1);
      if (tick === tickLimit) {
        clearInterval(inter);
        observer.complete(tickLimit);
      }
    }, milliSecs);
  }
};
```

Then, the effect of each of the following is identical:

```
Observable.interval(1000, 5).subscribe(someObserver);

const fiveSeconds = observableIntervalOf(1000, 5);
fiveSeconds(someObserver);
```

Am I right in assuming that its best to think of observables as partially applied functions? Are there instances where this is not the case?

Comment: No, what you have here is turning methods into partially applied functions. method `intervalObservable(x, y).subscribe(observer)` → procedure `subscribe(intervalObservable(x, y), observer)` → curried `subscribe(intervalObservable(x, y))(observer)` → shortcut `observableIntervalOf(x, y)(observer)`